# Spring Boot Test - Reduce Console Output

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

We are acutally using **Spring Boot 1.5.8** and as I can see, we haven't specified a specific logging framework. I'm responsible for JUnit tests as junior developer. We have about 17'000 Unit tests. When I run a lot of tests, IntelliJ can't or has performance issues with handling the console output. And I gave IntelliJ a lot of power ...

Now I adjusted the `Log.LEVEL` in `application.yml` to `WARN`, which works fine. But then I tried to **get rid of the HTTP response & request output** in the console. But even when I turn off the logging with

```
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
```

in `application.yml` it still shows HTTP requests & responses like this:

[image: IntelliJ console output]

this is filling up the console depending on the request with hundreds or thousand lines of **in some cases** unnecessary code!

I'm looking for an option to turn this off ... please help me. I was searching for a while, but couldn't find a answer. **Probably I'm on a completely wrong road** with looking after Spring Boot Logging. Thank you =)

---

**Edit:
 As an other example:**

I get an error an the following console output. I just need the first lines of the start and the red (+ some additional) lines. As you can see on the scrollbar, this is just a small piece of the complete output! Acutally **7033 lines** (!) are filled with HTTP request & responses like the one in the first picture.

[image: output start]
[image: output end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance I found the solution. I had to set `print = MockMvcPrint.NONE` in the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation. It seems like this collected the HTTP request & respones for each failed test and print everything whenever a test fails! This led to an tremendous output after some failures!

Answer (score 1):

Eek! You used:

```
logging:
level:
root: WARN
```

which  is yaml format! (it would work just fine if you renamed your file application.yml)

I believe you need to express it like this:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
```

which is the correct way to express it in an application.properties file.

Comment: I thought you have both options for configuring Spring? yml & properties? For me .yml solution worked, the console doesn't show any INFO or DEBUG logs.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry! I wrote properties, but is yml! sorry!

Comment: Sure, but it looks like you used yaml format in a file called application.properties :) .

Comment: ah no =) sorry, this was a mistake in the the post. The file is called application.yml & the format is like I described. But thanks for the hint.